# Xcode. Не открывает сайт на кириллице?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день!

Как открыть из приложения сайт, имя которого на кириллице?

```
    NSString *clickedSite = @"http://адрес.рф";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:clickedSite];
```

С англоязычными доменами все в норме - открывается браузер.
Или это только при тестировании на эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве все заработает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись без сторонних библиотек. Вот этот код поможет Вам открыть сайт на кириллице:

```
NSString *clickedSite = @"http://адрес.рф"; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[clickedSite stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел перекодировщик: [на гитхабе](https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa)

```
stringValue = stringValue.encodedURLString;
```

После чего адрес открылся.

Comment: Зачем использовать что-то стороннее, если можно использовать стандартное? 
Держите на будущее:
    NSString *clickedSite = @"http://адрес.рф";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[clickedSite stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: Спасибо! Если добавите как ответ - обязательно отмечу как правильный.